# System.InvalidOperationException: 'An async read operation has already been started on the stream

Tags: c#

i have write prog to get info about android devices 
i using external process 
create class apktool :
this code

namespace dream_tool
{
    class apktool
    {

```
    public StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    public Process cmd = new Process();

    public string RunExternalPing(string a)
    {


        cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        cmd.StartInfo.Arguments = a;
        cmd.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        cmd.OutputDataReceived +=
           new DataReceivedEventHandler(cmd_OutputDataReceived);
        //cmd.Exited += new EventHandler(cmd_Exited);
        cmd.Exited += new EventHandler(Form1.instance.cmd_Exited);

        cmd.Start();
        cmd.BeginOutputReadLine();
        cmd.WaitForExit();


        //   StreamWriter sw = cmd.StandardInput;
        //sw.WriteLine(a);

        // cmd.WaitForExit();

        // sw.Close();

        return a;
    }



    private void cmd_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 frm = new Form1();

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
        {
            output.Append(e.Data + Environment.NewLine);
        }
        cmd.CancelOutputRead();



    }



}
```

}
and in the form this code

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public static Form1 instance;
    apktool a2;
    Procees_adb a1 = new Procees_adb();
    List<String> fullFileName;

    public Form1()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        instance = this;
        a2 = new apktool();

    }
```

public void cmd_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        if (RCH_OUT.InvokeRequired)
        {
            RCH_OUT.Invoke(new EventHandler(delegate { RCH_OUT.Text = (a2.output.ToString()); }));
        }
        else
        {
            RCH_OUT.Text = (a2.output.ToString());
            MessageBox.Show(a2.output.ToString());
        }
        if(IsDisposed)
        {
            a2.cmd.Dispose();
        }


        //cmd.Dispose();
    }
```

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
         a2.RunExternalPing("/c adb shell getprop ro.product.cpu.abi");


    }
}
```

[when i press on button in first time i get info and that ok 
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlY53.png)

if i press it again 
it show me error on             cmd.BeginOutputReadLine();

System.InvalidOperationException: 'An async read operation has already been started on the stream.'
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ww92i.png)

the first problem solve by add             cmd.CancelOutputRead();

to

```
        private void cmd_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
```

but now  when press button second time the info Repeated 
Such as that in the picture
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZI1g.png)

Comment: Use await since it seems that previous call didn't finished yet.

Comment: i remove it not work

Comment: Have you checked msdn : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.beginoutputreadline(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: thx i use           cmd.CancelOutputRead();
 but i have problem now i well edit my post

Comment: now when press button second time the info Repeated Such as that in the picture   
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZI1g.png

Comment: Did you clear textbox after finishing first call ?

Comment: YES I CLEAR RICHBOX